# Como enviar codigos ASCII a un puerto serial y que se lean como bytes o caracteres? - C++

Tags: c++, puertos, ascii

En el siguiente código puedo mandar caracteres y que se lean los bytes de estos.
¿Pero que debo agregar, eliminar o modificar para que solo se envíen los códigos
ASCII y que se lean los bytes sin tener que agregar la linea `char bytes_to_send[] = "hello";`?

```
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>



int main()
{

    char bytes_to_send[] = "hello";
    bytes_to_send[0] = 104;
    bytes_to_send[1] = 101;
    bytes_to_send[2] = 108;
    bytes_to_send[3] = 108;
    bytes_to_send[4] = 111;


    HANDLE hSerial;
    DCB dcbSerialParams = { 0 };
    COMMTIMEOUTS timeouts = { 0 };


    fprintf(stderr, "Opening serial port...");
    hSerial = CreateFile(
        "\\\\.\\COM3", GENERIC_READ | GENERIC_WRITE, 0, NULL,
        OPEN_EXISTING, FILE_ATTRIBUTE_NORMAL, NULL);
    if (hSerial == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    else fprintf(stderr, "OK\n");


    dcbSerialParams.DCBlength = sizeof(dcbSerialParams);
    if (GetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error getting device state\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }

    dcbSerialParams.BaudRate = CBR_38400;
    dcbSerialParams.ByteSize = 8;
    dcbSerialParams.StopBits = ONESTOPBIT;
    dcbSerialParams.Parity = NOPARITY;
    if (SetCommState(hSerial, &dcbSerialParams) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting device parameters\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }


    timeouts.ReadIntervalTimeout = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.ReadTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutConstant = 50;
    timeouts.WriteTotalTimeoutMultiplier = 10;
    if (SetCommTimeouts(hSerial, &timeouts) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error setting timeouts\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }


    DWORD bytes_written, total_bytes_written = 0;
    fprintf(stderr, "Sending bytes...");
    if (!WriteFile(hSerial, bytes_to_send, 5, &bytes_written, NULL))
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        CloseHandle(hSerial);
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "%d bytes written\n", bytes_written);


    fprintf(stderr, "Closing serial port...");
    if (CloseHandle(hSerial) == 0)
    {
        fprintf(stderr, "Error\n");
        return 1;
    }
    fprintf(stderr, "OK\n");


    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Puedes hacer `char bytes_to_send[5]{}`

Answer (score 3):

En C++ hay varias formas de declarar un array o, en tu caso, un buffer:

- Tamaño definidio en tiempo de compilación. El compilador analiza el contenido a almacenar en el buffer y calcula el tamaño necesario para almacenarla:

  ```
  char array[] = "...";
  ```
- Tamaño definido explícitamente: El compilador no tiene que inferir el tamaño de buffer, se lo estás proporcionando de forma explícita:

  ```
  char array[200];
  ```
- Memoria dínamica. Te permite establecer el tamaño del buffer en función de las necesidades e cada momento:

  ```
  char* buffer;
  buffer = new char[200];

  // ...

  delete[] buffer;
  ```
- Contenedores. Añaden un nivel de encapsulación y aislamiento a los ejemplos anteriores:

  ```
  std::array<char,200> buffer; // Tamaño fijo
  buffer.data(); // Acceso al buffer interno

  std::vector<char> buffer; // Tamaño variable
  buffer.data(); // Acceso al buffer interno
  ```

Tu código está haciendo uso actualmente del primer ejemplo. Lo más rápido es sustituirlo por el segundo y, sin tocar nada, lo esperable es que todo funcione correctamente:

```
char bytes_to_send[6] = {}; // Se inicializan los bytes a 0
bytes_to_send[0] = 104;
bytes_to_send[1] = 101;
bytes_to_send[2] = 108;
bytes_to_send[3] = 108;
bytes_to_send[4] = 111;
```

Por otro lado piensa que la asignación que haces de los bytes es manual... sería más conveniente usar funciones de copia para evitar errores tontos:

```
char bytes_to_send[6];
strcpy(bytes_to_send,"hello");

// Esto ya sobra
// bytes_to_send[0] = 104;
// bytes_to_send[1] = 101;
// bytes_to_send[2] = 108;
// bytes_to_send[3] = 108;
// bytes_to_send[4] = 111;
```